# After bios reset, ubuntu os not working

Tags: boot, lenovo

I select "load default" in exit menu in bios setup. I have Ubuntu 16.04. after this, os is not loading showing " error partition not found, grub rescue>" what to do? HDD is in the first Lenovo BIOS boot priority. Mount sda2 not working, saying  read permission only in the terminal in live ubuntu

Details:
  Product : Lenovo g500
  Bios version : 78CN25WW (V2.03)

Comment: Need help guys...

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system (ie. Ubuntu install media) and look at what is there.  What your 'load default' did is very hardware specific; and you haven't mentioned what box (make/model etc) you are using.

Comment: I have Lenovo g500

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)